# Showing that multilinear maps factor through tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M_{1},...M_{n},L$ be $R$-modules.  Let $\iota:M_{1},...M_{n}\rightarrow M_{1}\bigotimes...\bigotimes M_{n}$ be defined by $\iota(m_{1},...,m_{n})\mapsto m_{1}\otimes...\otimes m_{n}$ and let $\phi:M_{1}\times...\times M_{n}\rightarrow L$ be an $n$-multilinear map.  Claim: there is a unique $R$-module homomorphism $\Phi:M_{1}\bigotimes...\bigotimes M_{n}\mapsto L$  such that $\phi =\Phi \circ \iota$.

Assume this holds for $n=2$ (in other words, assume the universal property for the tensor product of pairs of modules).  I want to show that this case implies the remaining cases, for example, $n=3$.  Apparently this is immediate, but I have absolutely no idea why it is true.  I have tried every way of pairing the modules but nothing has worked.

Edit: I am using the construction from free groups, etc. definition of tensor products.

Comment: Normally one defines the $n$-fold tensor product to be a vector space $M_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes M_n$ equipped with a linear map $\iota \colon M_1 \times \ldots \times M_n \to M_1 \otimes \ldots M_n$ which satisfies the universal property that you describe, and then the notation $m_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes m_n$ is by definition $\iota(m_1, \ldots, m_n)$.  With this definition your claim is a tautology.  But one must prove that the $n$-fold tensor product actually exists - perhaps you're trying to show that the $3$-fold tensor product exists if the $2$-fold tensor product exists?

Answer (score -2):

#### Existence

$\Phi: m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_n \mapsto \phi(m_1, \cdots, m_n)$ satisfies the condition.

#### Uniqueness

Let $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$ be maps satisfying the condition.

Then, I will prove that $\Phi = \Phi'$.

Let $m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_n \in M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_n$. Then:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\Phi(m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_n)
&=& \Phi(\iota(m_1,\cdots,m_n)) \\
&=& \phi(m_1,\cdots,m_n) \\
&=& \Phi'(\iota(m_1,\cdots,m_n)) \\
&=& \Phi'(m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_n)
\end{array}$$

Comment: Why is that $\Phi$ what you claim it is?  For example, why is it well-defined?

Comment: I don't think you can get around having to use the universal property for tensor products of pairs of modules.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd what is it with not providing a definition and then downvoting others for using different definitions?

Comment: Sorry I tried upvoting you afterwards but it went to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Your answer sort of trivializes the question doesn't it?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd what if the question itself is trivial?

Comment: Then I would like to see the trivial answer...